# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error in Hangman Game

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and for my AP Computer Science Class, we are creating a hangman game.

In my method `guessCheck` , I have a enhanced for loop that checks if `letterGuess` matches any letter in `masterWord`. If it matches, it replaces the index of `censoredWord` with `letterGuess`. The line of code that gives me a problem is `censoredWord[x] = letterGuess;`. Why is it throwing a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error?

```
public class Hangman {

    static String[] wordList = new String[]{"wait", "release", "important", "mark", "electric", "defective", "poke",
        "blue", "beef", "spring", "hurt", "orange", "happy", "zealous", "flowery", "accurate", "brake", "title",
        "festive", "wrathful", "scissors", "peaceful", "finicky", "shape", "soothe", "head", "spotted", "needless",
        "time", "abundant", "humdrum", "mouth", "trot", "bounce", "thank", "avoid", "shocking", "minor", "secret"};

    static int lives = 5;
    static String placeholder = wordList[(int) (Math.random() * wordList.length)];
    static char[] MasterCopyWord = placeholder.toCharArray();
    static String playerName;
    static char censoredWord[] = new char[placeholder.length()];
    static boolean didIWin = false;
    static char[] guessedChars = new char[26];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        initGame();

        // game starting screen and info
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String playerName = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + playerName
                               + ", you are playing Hangman where you try to guess a random word. You have 5 lives.");
        // Game start text
        System.out.println("The game will start! Guess the word by typing a one letter at a time!");
        System.out.println("Guess your " + MasterCopyWord.length + " letter word!");
        System.out.println(censoredWord);
        System.out.print("Cheat: Chosen word is ");
        System.out.println(placeholder);
        System.out.println("Guessed Letters:" + new String(guessedChars));

        // game loop
        while (!didIWin) {
            char guess = sc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Guessed Letters:" + new String(guessedChars));
            System.out.print("Cheat: Chosen word is ");
            System.out.println(placeholder);
            guessCheck(guess);
            System.out.println(censoredWord);
        }
    }

    // check if letterGuess is correct
    public static void guessCheck(char letterGuess) {

        for (char y : guessedChars) {
            if (guessedChars[y] == '\u0000') {
                guessedChars[y] = letterGuess;
            }
        }

//iterates through masterWord, replacing any
//matching letters in censoredWord
        for (char x : MasterCopyWord) {
            if (x == letterGuess) {
                censoredWord[x] = letterGuess;

            } else {
                lives--;
            }

            // check for lives
            boolean wordMatch = Arrays.equals(MasterCopyWord, censoredWord);
            if (lives <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You lost!");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (wordMatch) {
                System.out.println("Congrats " + playerName
                                       + "! You correctly guessed the word! The game will now terminate");
                didIWin = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void initGame() {
        // makes copy of chosen word and censors it
        for (int x = 0; x < placeholder.length(); x++) {
            censoredWord[x] = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `x` is of a type `char`, what do you think the expression `censoredWord[x]` does? Hint - if `x == '1'`, the `censoredWord[x]` does **not** equal `censoredWord[1]`.

Comment: array indexes (censoredWord[arrayIndex]) must be numbers, not characters.  I'm a little surprised the compiler let you do that, but it must be autobox casting the character to an integer, which won't do what you want in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'x' is the character of the guess (type char), and cannot be used as an index in the string( this is a number not a character). You need to know the index to replace it in your censored word. perhaps instead of

```
for(char x: MasterCopyWord)
```

you should instead iterate numerically through the word

```
for(int i = 0; i < MasterCopyWord.length(); i++) {
    if( MasterCopyWord[i] == letterGuess) {
       censoredWord[i] = letterGuess;
    } else {...
```